# Java programming idiom : Private implementation class

Tags: java, private-members, pimpl-idiom, private-class

I found this construct in some code.

Is there any benefit to have a private static class implement A? This reminded me of the Pimpl idiom in C++. Is there any benefit to using the Pimpl idiom in Java?

```
public abstract class A {
    public void doStuff();

    public static A getNewInstance() {
       return new AImpl();
    }

    private static class AImpl extends A {
        public void doStuff()  {
           ....
        }    
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is there any benefit to have a private static class implement A?

Well, it hides the implementation away completely, so from an encapsulation point of view it's quite nice. One situation I've seen this in a few times is custom comparators. For example:

```
public class Person
{
    public static final Comparator<Person> NAME_COMPARATOR = new NameComparator();
    public static final Comparator<Person> AGE_COMPARATOR = new AgeComparator();

    // Name, age etc properties

    private static class NameComparator implements Comparator<Person>
    {
        ...
    }

    private static class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Person>
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

There's no real need for the comparator implementation classes to be visible outside `Person`, and it's nice to be able to get an instance easily via the public static field.

No callers need to know the implementation - there could just be *one* comparator class which takes parameters, for example - they just express which comparator they want via the constants. (You could equally use an enum for this, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But isn't it better to have `NameComparator` and `AgeComparator` as non-public classes? I'm not sure, but doesn't adding a static inner class make it binary incompatible?

Comment: @Chip: If they're non-public classes outside `Person`, they're still available in the same package when they really don't need to be. Adding a static inner class *may* change the serialization UID unless you specify it explicitly, but binary serialization in Java is so horrible that I don't use it anyway. I don't believe it will affect binary compatibility of simply running the code.

Comment: Thanks Jon. It makes sense if it does not break binary compatibility. For the design to be flexible, I would want to be able to add another class, say `AImpl2` the same way, and not break older clients.

Comment: I was excited about this, but I just found out that private variables inside NameComparator and AgeComparator are visible to each other. Guess they are not "first class" classes.

Comment: @Chip: Yes, the accessibilty of private members within nested classes is interesting... but it's at least *somewhat* limited.

Comment: Yes.. its a decision between "hiding from the rest of the package" vs "hiding from each other". Not ideal, but I'll have to go with one or the other